# How to retain custom layer names and avoid "TensorFlowOpLayer" in json model export

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am training a sequential `tf.keras` model which I want to convert to `tfjs` format consisting of a `model.json` file describing the layers and binary weight files to deploy it on a website for inference.

Two layers in my model are custom layers since there are no suitable layers predefined in `tf.keras.layers` to do the job. This is a mock version of what my model code looks like:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class SliceChannelsLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    ... (model implementation) ...

class L1NormLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    ... (model implementation) ...

def sequential_model():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(30, 36, 36, 6), batch_size=None)
    outputs_a = SliceChannelsLayer(start=0, end=3)(inputs)
    outputs_b = SliceChannelsLayer(start=3, end=6)(inputs)
    ...
    other Keras layers
    ...
    attention = L1NormLayer(1)(attention)
    outputs_motion = tf.keras.layers.Multiply()([outputs_a, attention])
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs_b)

model = sequential_model()
```

In my JavaScript code, I have implemented the two custom layers as [outlined in the example given in tfjs-examples](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/blob/master/custom-layer/custom_layer.js):

```
class SliceChannelsLayer extends tf.layers.Layer {
  ... (model implementation) ...
}

class L1NormLayer extends tf.layers.Layer {
  ... (model implementation) ...
}
```

When running `tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, "tfjs_export")`, both custom layers receive the *same* name in `model.json`: `TensorFlowOpLayer`.

However, I need to match the names of my JavaScript layer implementations to these names which is impossible when multiple layers receive the same name.
My code works when I manually edit the `model.json` file to replace `TensorFlowOpLayer` with `SliceChannelsLayer` or `L1NormLayer`.

**My question**: How can I avoid having to manually change the layer names in `model.json` after exporting?

Edit: The behaviour can be reproduced with the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflowjs as tfjs

class L1NormLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """L1NormLayer"""
    def __init__(self, axis, **kwargs):
        super(L1NormLayer, self).__init__()
        self.axis = axis
    def __call__(self, inputs):
        inputs, _ = tf.linalg.normalize(inputs, ord=1, axis=self.axis)
        return inputs

class SliceChannelsLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """SliceChannelsLayer"""
    def __init__(self, start, end, **kwargs):
        super(SliceChannelsLayer, self).__init__()
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
    def __call__(self, inputs):
        inputs = inputs[:, :, :, :, self.start:self.end]
        return inputs

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(29, 36, 36, 6), batch_size=1)
outputs_a = SliceChannelsLayer(start=0, end=3, name="SliceChannels")(inputs)
outputs_b = SliceChannelsLayer(start=3, end=6, name="SliceChannels")(inputs)
attention = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        filters=1, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation="sigmoid"))(
            outputs_b)
attention = L1NormLayer(1, name="L1Norm")(attention)
outputs_a = tf.keras.layers.Multiply()([outputs_b, attention])
outputs_a = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation="linear")(outputs_a)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs_a)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop())

model.summary()

tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, "tfjs")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__call__` method should be `call` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just tried this, and I still get `TensorFlowOpLayer` both in `model.summary()` and in the exported `model.json`.

Comment: Could you please add the complete implementation of the python custom model ? Additionnally, do you mean that the model.summary() in the python code outputs `TensorFlowOpLayer` as the layers name or does it happen only in the js code ?

Comment: I have added a code snippet that will hopefully let you reproduce the problem. Regarding your other question, the layer appears as `tf_op_layer_strided_slice_1` and `tf_op_layer_normalize` in `model.summary()`. When you search in `model.json`, you'll find that the models appear as `TensorFlowOpLayer` instead of `SliceChannelsLayer` and `L1NormLayer`.

Comment: I just realized that the error is because of `__call__` instead of `call`